# How to left-align using eqnarray in latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

Now, first of all let me get something clear: I do not ask for any reasons why `align` is btter than `eqnarray`. All I ask is a simple way to make this work, using eqnarray (It's obviously possible, but I'm not sure how).

```
\begin{eqnarray}~\label{eqn07}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
$\Psi_{1}(x,\lambda)$ & = & & $ U(x,\lambda)e_{1} $ \cr
&   & & \cr
\end {tabular}
\end {eqnarray}
```

Yet after compiling it, I get the equation centered, instead of left-aligned. I've tried to insert `\left{ ... \right}` , but it wouldn't even build, and I just had many errors popping up. Could someone tell me a simple way to do so, wihout using `\begin{align}`. I do want to use `\begin{eqnarray}` (I've got my own reasons why).

Comment: What do you mean by "left-aligned"? The default behaviour of `eqnarray` is to provide a `r`ight-`c`entre-`l`eft alignment of the three components of the equation. Collectively, the entire structure is centred. Do you want the entire structure to be left-aligned?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the `fleqn` option to your document class. Regardless, the following is the correct way of using `eqnarray`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
  \Psi_{1}(x,\lambda) & = & U(x,\lambda)e_{1}\label{eqn07}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

You'll notice that the equation is left-aligned, although not flush with the left margin. To achieve this, add `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` to the document preamble as well.

Note that you don't need `eqnarray` for a single equation. For this, the `equation` environment is sufficient. However, since the spacing of `eqnarray` is inferior to the regular math spacing, it might be better for consistency.

Comment: And one doesn't need `eqnarray` at all.